# How can I count items in mongo collection that have intersecting subcollections?

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-.net-driver

For every item in my collection I need to find count of other items that have intersecting subcollections. For example,
given this collection

```
[{id:1,"sub":[1, 2, 3]},
{id:2,"sub":[2, 3, 4]},
{id:3,"sub":[4, 5, 6],
{id:4,"sub":[7, 8, 9]}]
```

expected result is

```
[{id:1,"count":1},
{id:2,"count":2},
{id:3,"count":1},
{id:4,"count":0"}]
```

Comment: Are you sure your expected result is correct as `3` has a count of `2` and `4` has a count of `2`?

Comment: Sure, `1` intersects only with `2`,`2` intersects with both `1` and `3`, `3` intersects with only `2`, `4` doesn't intersect with any

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting with the algorithm in pure MongoDB query language: You have to restructure your documents so that each document contains it's initial `sub` array and an array of all the other `sub` values. To do that you need to run [$group](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/index.html) along with [$unwind](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/index.html). Then it becomes easy to just run [$map](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/index.html) with [$setIntersect](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setIntersection/index.html) [$filter](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/index.html) out all empty and equal to self arrays and get the size using [$size](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/size/index.html)

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $group: {
            _id: null,
            current: { $push: "$$ROOT" },
            all: { $push: "$sub" }
        }
    },
    {
        $unwind: "$current"
    },
    {
        $project: {
            id: "$current.id",
            count: {
                $size: {
                    $filter: {
                        input: {
                            $map: {
                                input: "$all",
                                in: { $setIntersection: [ "$$this", "$current.sub" ] }
                            }
                        },
                        cond: {
                            $and: [ 
                                { $ne: [ "$$this", [] ] },
                                { $ne: [ "$$this", "$current.sub" ]}
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/TyaLkgTCGC_)

Since the aggregation is quite complex there's no point in running it in a strongly-typed way in C#. All you can do is to use `BsonDocument` class to build your pipeline like:

```
var groupDef = new BsonDocument()
        {
            { "_id", "" },
            { "current", new BsonDocument(){ { "$push", "$$ROOT" } } },
            { "all", new BsonDocument(){ { "$push", "$sub" } } },
        };

var projectDef = BsonDocument.Parse(@"{
        id: ""$current.id"",
        _id: 0,
        count: {
        $size: {
            $filter: {
            input: {
                $map: {
                input: ""$all"",
                in: {
                    $setIntersection: [
                    ""$$this"",
                    ""$current.sub""
                    ]
                }
                }
            },
            cond: {
                $and: [
                {
                    $ne: [
                    ""$$this"",
                    []
                    ]
                },
                {
                    $ne: [
                    ""$$this"",
                    ""$current.sub""
                    ]
                }
                ]
            }
            }
        }
        }
    }");

var result = mongoDBCollection.Aggregate()
                                .Group(groupDef)
                                .Unwind("current")
                                .Project(projectDef)
                                .ToList();
```

Comment: Beautiful! Works like a charm! Thank you!

Comment: yeah this dude is a mongodb god :-)